# Подсчитать максимально количество совпадающих записей mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:

```
a | b
-----
1 | 1  
1 | 2  
2 | 3  
2 | 4  
3 | 1  
3 | 2  
4 | 1  
4 | 3
```

Необходимо выбрать два значения столбца a, у которых максимальное количество общих значений по столбцу b.

Comment: Что вы сами пытались сделать, что не получилось ?

Comment: Добавте ваш запрос. Воспользуйтесь кнопкой - [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/656145/edit)

Comment: Какой результат ожидается для приведенного примера?

Comment: Связываете две копии таблицы по равенству второго поля, группируете по обоим первым полям и сортируете по убыванию количества записей в группе.

Comment: @Yaant видимо, 1 и 3.

Comment: @Yaant Все верно, результат должен быть 1 и 3.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за совет. сейчас попробую. вообще не понятно было как сделать это одним запросом. проще вытащить данные и посчитать, но в условии задачи именно один запрос.

Comment: @NoName А если в таблице будет еще строчки `5 | 1` и `5 | 3`?

Comment: @Yaant При равных условиях достаточно любой пары. Ниже дан подходящий ответ. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто - делаем соединение таблицы саму с собой по одинаковому полю b и разным полям a (ставим дополнительно условие `t1.a < t2.a`, чтобы не было повторяющихся пар типа 1,3 и 3,1). После этого смотрим количество совпадений у данной строки, берем самую первую из них, она и будет содержать два столбца с наибольшим совпадением.

```
select t1.a, t2.a, count(*) as cnt
from test t1 join test t2 ON t1.b = t2.b and t1.a < t2.a
group by t1.a, t2.a
order by cnt desc limit 1
```

[Пример на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/824c30/7).